# What makes linear operator of norm 1 special?

Tags: functional-analysis

Actually I'm not sure about how to illustrate my question since it is based on some observations I made during these days, when learning functional analysis. I observed that **operators with norm 1** are always mentioned in either theorems in our lecture notes or our assignments. For instance

> A corollary of Hahn-Banach's theorem: Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $M\subset X$ be a subspace. There is a vector $x_0\in X$ such that $d=\rho(x_0,M)>0$. Then there exists $f\in X^*$(the space of bounded linear functionals on $X$), satisfies 1. $f\big|_{M}=0$;  2.$f(x_0)=d$;  3. $\|f\|=1$.

> A property of **operator of orthogonal projection**: In a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with a closed subspace $X_0$, the operator of orthogonal projection is defined as: $\mathcal{P}:X\rightarrow X_0, x\mapsto z$, where $x$ can be uniquelly written as $x=y+z, y\in X_0, z\in X_0^{\perp}.$ The norm of such operator is $\left\|\mathcal{P}\right\|=1.$

Morever, if one consider Riesz's repretation theorem, it can be observed that the norm of a functional $f$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is exatly $\|f\|=\|y\|$, where $f$ is represented by inner product $(x,y)$ for all $x\in \mathcal{H}$ and some certain $y\in \mathcal{H}$.
etc......
I was wondering that if someone can give me a brief explaination, better geometrically, on what is so special about operators of norm 1? And morever, what does the norm of a operator means, geographically?

Comment: Geographically?  Or geometrically?

Comment: sorry! my bad, a careless mistake